# Is it possible to redirect Outlook 2010 to Gmail?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, gmail

Things have been set up on my school email so that everything comes into Outlook on my computer. I hate outlook and want everything redirected to my gmail account.

I've seen something here:
http://answers.vt.edu/kb/entry/1147/
That implies it is impossible, but would like some confirmation that this is really so.

[Note this isn't my school - my school has given me no instructions].

I have also tried the advice here http://www.howcast.com/videos/395621-How-to-Redirect-Email-From-Outlook-to-Gmail-or-Hotmail

But then I get the error message "You cannot combine server-only actions with client-only conditions or actions."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Gmail account you want to go to "Settings" and "Accounts" and click "Add a POP3 mail account you own" and add the account to Gmail.

**EDIT:** Seeing that this is a School Gmail account I would go to the School Gmail account and choose "Settings" then "Forwarding and POP/IMAP" "click "ADD a forwarding address" which will forward the emails to your own email account.

Comment: Thanks. But how would i find the POP3 details for my outlook account?

Comment: Open outlook and go to account Setting and click change on the Email account you want to check in Gmail or go to your ISPs webstie they all have info pages on the email information.

Comment: Thanks. But how can I be sure my other email supports POP access?

Comment: One issue regarding your EDIT suggestion is that it isn't a school gmail account. The school only offers outlook, not gmail.

Comment: What other account? In outlook what does it say POP or IMAP either can be setup in Gmail. But with this being a school they may not allow it, I would use the Forward method instead.

Comment: OK then if they allow you to see the information in Outlook you can try to set in up in Gmail to be checked.

Comment: One option would be to setup automatic forward in outlook to your Gmail account if all else fails.

Comment: Got it working via your suggestion to visit Gmail Settings. Thanks!

Comment: Your Welcome glad to help.